# Theme Customizer for only author.php (per user baisi)

Tags: theme-customizer

How can the Wordpress Theme Customizer be used only for `author.php` and settings will be saved per user basis. By which every user can customize their own `author.php`.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Exactly what setting are you trying to manipulate?

Comment: options data to user_meta @s_ha_dum

Comment: Please be specific. That doesn't tell me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to use Wordpress Theme Customize API https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API to give user options to modify their own auhtor.php. Theme Customize API save all its settings to wp_options table. If somehow it can be done to save user_meta per user basis. It could be possible to allow user to use Theme customizer only for author.php

Comment: You can add a capability on Customizer, that only roles with this capability can use the Customizer.

Comment: @bueltge but adding capability will only limit on access, but will not save customizer api data per user basis.

Comment: @s_ha_dum any idea?

Comment: $wp_customize->add_setting($id, $args); have a optional parameter to set a capability. Use this to set the custom capability from your author and only this role can change the settings.

Comment: Idea? I think you are doing this the wrong way. If you want "per author" customization you should be using the user profiles instead of the theme customizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to generate customizer settings depending on the current user. So there are two conditions to be met: the setting must only be accessible to the current user and this setting must be unique to him.

```
// Only do this for contributors and up
if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
   // retrieve author id
   global $current_user;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   $author_id = $current_user->ID
   // generate customizer setting for this author only
   $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_color_' . $author_id , array(
     'default' => '#000',
     'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
     'capability' => 'edit_posts',
     ));
```

In (the heading of) your `author.php` you will need to get the id of the author of the current page to retrieve the relevant mod.

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
get_mod('header_color_' . $author_id);
```

Comment: How it can be saved and read from user_meta? Can it be achieved any way?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. The customizer has a 'save' button. You retrieve the saved data with `get_mod`. You don't need to write save or read functions yourself.

Comment: I want customizer data to save in user_meta field instead of in wp_option table. This way each user will have their own data on user_meta table. And with this data each author.php page can be modified. How can I achieve this?